# How to replace the response in the webview2 using rust

Tags: rust, webview2, tauri

I write a program with tauri. I want to intercept the request and replace the response content. But i can't get the response, when the program execute 'args.Response().unwrap', it throw some errors:

```
let window = tauri::WindowBuilder::new(<some args>).build().unwrap();
let _ = window.with_webview(|webview| unsafe {
      let core = webview.controller().CoreWebView2().unwrap();
      let _ = core.AddWebResourceRequestedFilter(PCWSTR::null(), COREWEBVIEW2_WEB_RESOURCE_CONTEXT_SCRIPT);
      let _ = core.add_WebResourceRequested(
            &WebResourceRequestedEventHandler::create(Box::new(move |_webview, args| {
               if let Some(args) = args {
                    let response = args.Response().unwrap(); // called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { code: 0x00000000, message: The operation completed successfully. }
                    response.SetContent(<How to construct this argument>);
               }
               Ok(())
            })),
            &mut EventRegistrationToken::default()
       );
});
```

My questions is :

1. why 'args.Response().unwrap()' throw error "The operation completed successfully.", how to deal with this situation;
2. if i can get a response, how to replace the content (how to construct the argument).